# How to hover over an image with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I been trying to write a code which able to mouseover on image which can hover the image up and down. All of these have not worked.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here my code :

```js
   jQuery.easing['jswing'] = jQuery.easing['swing'];
   jQuery.extend(jQuery.easing, {
     easeOutBounce: function(x, t, b, c, d) {
       if ((t /= d) < (1 / 2.75)) {
         return c * (7.5625 * t * t) + b
       } else if (t < (2 / 2.75)) {
         return c * (7.5625 * (t -= (1.5 / 2.75)) * t + .75) + b
       } else if (t < (2.5 / 2.75)) {
         return c * (7.5625 * (t -= (2.25 / 2.75)) * t + .9375) + b
       } else {
         return c * (7.5625 * (t -= (2.625 / 2.75)) * t + .984375) + b
       }
     }
   });

   $('.game_wvm').hover(function() {
     $(this).stop().animate({
       top: -50
     }, 900, "easeOutBounce");
   }, function() {
     $(this).stop().animate({
       top: 0
     }, 900, "easeOutBounce");
   });
```

```css
.game_wvm {
  position: relative;
  /* To animate the `top` position */
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <em class="game_wvm"></em> //getting imageURL
  <div class="game-name">金刚狼</div>
  <div class="game-rollover clearfix"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="real-play">立刻开始</a>
  </div>
  <p class="game-progressive">￥<span></span>
  </p>
</li>
```

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? it seems to bounce for me

Comment: on my image it's not moving either , not sure what problem

Comment: It's bouncing the image for me(Firefox latest version)

Comment: It's working on my Chrome as well. What browser are you using ?